# Externally updated RTF content controls in Word

Tags: formatting, heading, word-contentcontrol

How do you get word to maintain its styles when you have an externally updated content control?

I have multiple RTF content controls that get updated from an external source. I want to lay them out so they are chapters in the document. I use Heading 1 on the first control and then heading 2 on the second control.

When I run the update the Headings are removed.

I tried changing the position of where the control sits in relation to the heading, it had no effect.